# How can I make a Map annotation callout open a new viewcontroller in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, mkmapview, mapkit, callout

I'm trying to open a new view by clicking on a map callout. 

In obj-C my code was this:

```
//Callout
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{
if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]])
{
    Annotation *myAnn = (Annotation *)view.annotation;
    id vcToPush = nil;
    if ([[myAnn title] isEqualToString:@"View1"]){
        vcToPush = [[View1 alloc]init];
    }
    if ([[myAnn title] isEqualToString:@"View2"]){
        vcToPush = [[View2 alloc]init];
    }
    if ([[myAnn title] isEqualToString:@"View3"]){
        vcToPush = [[View3 alloc]init];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcToPush animated:YES];
 }
}
```

What's the equivalent in Swift? 
At the moment I've got this, but I'm stuck:

```
//Pin type and callout
func mapView(_mapView: MKMapView!,
    viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "pin"

        var pinView = MapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        var rightCalloutAccessoryView: UIView!
        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView!.canShowCallout = true
            pinView!.pinColor = .Red

            pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton
        }
        else {
            pinView!.annotation = annotation

        }
        return pinView
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {

}
```

I've had a look around but the only answers I can find are not really solving my problem.
Thanx for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
func mapView(MapView: MKMapView!, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("NameOfYourSegue", sender: self)
        println("Going to the next VC!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be something like this. If you are using the title as identifier you don't need to verify if it's your custom class, since it also has title.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView,
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        let location = view.annotation as! MKAnnotation
        if (location.title == "Name 1") {
           performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue1", sender: self)
        } else if (location.title == "Name 2")  {
           performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue2", sender: self)
        }  
}
```